# How to operate bitwise operation on varbinary datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, bitwise-operators, varbinarymax

I have two very big numbers like (2^1000) and ((2^768)-234) as varbinary(MAX).
I want to operate & (AND) operation between these two numbers, but SQL Server does not support this operation.

What's your idea to solve the problem?

My T-SQL:

```
 SELECT 
     (CAST(12345678901234567890 AS VARBINARY(MAX))) 
        & CAST(9876543210987654321 AS VARBINARY(MAX))
```

Error from SQL Server:

> The data types varbinary(max) and varbinary(max) are incompatible in the '&' operator.

Comment: using CLR would be the easiest solution. BTW the datatypes of those literals are decimal not integer so casting them to binary wont give the results you expect anyway.

Comment: Bitwise operators only operate on integer data in SQL Server.